# How to use if/else loop in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use `if/else-if/else` loop in helm chart. Basically, I want to add ENV configs in configfile based on the if/else condition. Below is the logic:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}-configmap
  labels:
    projectName: {{ .Values.applicationName }}
    environment: {{ .Values.environment }}
    type: configmap
data:
{{- if eq .Values.environment "production" }}
{{ .Files.Get "config-prod.yaml" | nindent 2}}
{{- else if eq .Values.environment "development" }}
{{ .Files.Get "config-dev.yaml" | nindent 2}}
{{- else }}
{{ .Files.Get "config-stage.yaml" | nindent 2}}
{{- end }}
```

But I am not getting the desired output and facing some issue. Can anybody help me out with this?

Edit1: I have added my modified configmap.yaml as per the suggestions, helm install/template command gives `Error: YAML parse error on demo2/templates/configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: did not find expected key` error.

also my config-prod and config-stage is being rendered (as per the condition if I give `environment: production` then config-prod.yaml is being added and if I give `environment: stage/null` then config-stage.yaml is being added.

Answer (score 3):

Your question would benefit from more specifics.

Please consider adding the following to your question:

- How are you trying this? What commands exactly did you run?
- How are you "not getting the desired output"? What output did you get?

Please also include:

- the relevant entries from your `values.yaml`
- the `config-dev.yaml` and `config-stage.yaml` files

Have you run [helm template](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/) to generate the templates that Helm would apply to your cluster? This would be a good way to diagnose the issue.

I wonder whether you're chomping too much whitespace.

And you should just chomp left, i.e. `{{- .... }}` rather than left+right `{{- ... -}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, it was my mistake, my dev-config.yaml has envs and it was defined like key=value, instead of key: value.